# force:editRecord doesn't appear

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am in lightning experience using a custom component in a custom tab. Previously force:createRecord worked just fine when this button was clicked. I changed the code to force:editRecord and now nothing happens when this button is clicked.

```
createQuestion : function(component, event, helper) {
    var editRecord = $A.get("e.force:editRecord");

    editRecord.setParams({
        "recordID": component.get("v.currentQuestion.Id")
    });

    editRecord.fire();
},
```

---

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="QuestionViewerController" >

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{! c.doInit }"/>
<aura:handler name="QuestionAddedEvent" action="{! c.reloadQuestions }" event="c:QuestionAddedEvent"/>

<aura:attribute name="title" type="String" required="true" default="Question Viewer"/>
<aura:attribute name="Questions" type="Question__c[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="currentQuestion" type="Question__c"/>
<aura:attribute name="index" type="Integer" />
<aura:attribute name="bodyEmpty" type="Boolean"/>

<lightning:card title="{!'Question: ' + v.currentQuestion.Name}" class="slds-p-horizontal_medium">
    <div class="slds-grid--verticle">
        <div class="slds-col slds-no-flex">

            <aura:if isTrue="{! v.bodyEmpty }">
                    <lightning:formattedText class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-no-flex" title="{!v.currentQuestion.Name}" value="{!v.currentQuestion.Explanation__c}"/>
                <aura:set attribute="else">
                    <lightning:formattedText class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-no-flex" title="{!v.currentQuestion.Name}" value="{!v.currentQuestion.body__c}"/>    
                </aura:set>
            </aura:if> 

        </div>
        <div class="slds-p-top_medium slds-p-bottom_medium">
            <lightning:formattedText aura:id="answer" class="slds-text-heading_small slds-no-flex slds-hide slds-box" value="{! v.currentQuestion.answer__c }"/>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-no-flex slds-theme_info">
            <button class="slds-button" onclick="">
                <lightning:icon iconName="action:back" size="small" alternativeText="Do something" />
            </button>

            <button class="slds-button" onclick="">
                <lightning:icon iconName="action:delete" size="small" alternativeText="Do something" />
            </button>

            <button class="slds-button" onclick="{! c.createQuestion }">
                <lightning:icon iconName="action:flow" size="small" alternativeText="Do something" />
            </button>

            <button class="slds-button" onclick="{! c.showAnswer }">
                <lightning:icon iconName="action:new_campaign" size="small" alternativeText="Do something" />
            </button>

            <button class="slds-button" onclick="{! c.nextQuestion }">
                <lightning:icon iconName="action:refresh" size="small" alternativeText="Do something" />
            </button>

            <lightning:formattedText class="slds-p-horizontal_small" value="{! v.currentQuestion.Category__c }" />
        </div> 
    </div>
</lightning:card>
```

Comment: have you tried changing recordID to recordId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute Parameters are case sensitive, when you are setting the recordId, makse sure the casing is correct:

> recordID

is invalid, as far as I am concerned, this will throw an error (if you are capturing it, however, by the looks of your code, you aren't.)

the correct syntax is:

> recordId

I encourage you to add exception handling and capture error messages to debug your code.